# ¿Error al subir .docx con Php?

Tags: php

Hola a todos cargo distintos tipos de archivos y los guardo en una carpeta y almaceno en la BD la ruta, todos los archivos los carga bien (.doc, xls...)excepto (docx,xlsx...) los archivos .Docx lo copia al directorio pero no es posible obtener su nombre, tamaño tipo etc.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if($_POST) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "../archivos/" . $nombre;    

    copy($ruta, $destino);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (tipo,tamano,destino,fecha) VALUES ('$tipo', '$tamanio', '$nombre',NOW())";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    $connect->close();

}
```

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, ¿ tienes problemas con los nombres de archivo con mayúsculas ? ¿ Sistema operativo del cliente y del servidor ? ¿ algún *log* o mensaje de error ? (php, apache, lo que sea). -1. Ya llevas tiempo en el sitio.

Comment: No me muestra ningún  error todos lo archivos los sube bien excepto  los docx

Comment: ¿ Unica y exclusivamente los .docx ? Raro, muy raro. Así *a pelo*, sin mas info ... En fin, edita la pregunta (cualquier cosa) y retiro -1

Comment: Lección aprendida. Para otra vez, primero pongo el comentario, y después voto :-(

Answer (score 0):

podrias crear un arreglo con los formatos validos para subir.

```
$formatos = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "zip", "rar", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf");
```

despues podrias validar la extensión del archivo.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
 foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
  if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue;
      } 
  elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $formatos) ){
                    $message[] = "$name formtato no valido";
                    continue; 
                }
      }
}
```

maso menos seria de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es en el mimes.php

En la línea correspondiente a doc y docx, cambia por lo siguiente:

```
'doc'   =>  array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'),
'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip','application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text','application/octet-stream'),
```

Asimismo, asegúrate de que acepte archivos con extensión doc y docx. Por ejemplo:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet | application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text | application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation |
```

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document | application/vnd.ms-excel | application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation|txt|gif|jpg|png|pdf|ods|odt|xls|xlsx|docx|doc';